# respond-to-auth-challenge returns erros: Invalid session provided

Tags: amazon-cognito

### Summery

I"m gonna try to set new password for user which is created by `admin-create-user`.

```
$ aws cognito-idp admin-create-user \
--user-pool-id ap-northeast-1_xxxxxxxx \
--username test@example.com \
--user-attributes \
  Name=email,Value=test@example.com \
  Name=email_verified,Value=True \
  Name=given_name,Value=hoge \
  Name=family_name,Value=fuga \
  Name=custom:hoge,Value=fuga
```

When I logged in for the first time, `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` is required.

```
$ aws cognito-idp initiate-auth \
--client-id client-id-xxxx \
--auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \
--auth-parameters \
    USERNAME=test@example.com,PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx

{
    "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
    "Session": "session"
    "ChallengeParameters": {
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "session-xxxxx",
        "requiredAttributes": "[]",
        "userAttributes": "{\"email_verified\":\"True\",\"custom:department\":\"
    }
}
```

So I called `respond-to-auth-challenge` to resolve `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` status.
But it returned error even though I set the same session returned by `initiate-auth`.

```
$ aws cognito-idp respond-to-auth-challenge \
--client-id client-id-xxxx \
--challenge-responses "NEW_PASSWORD=Password1234,USERNAME=test@example.com" \
--challenge-name NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED \
--session session-xxxxx

An error occurred (CodeMismatchException) when calling the RespondToAuthChallenge operation: Invalid session provided
```

I want to know how to resolve this error.

(※ I called `initiate-auth` and `respond-to-auth-challenge`, not `admin-xxx` because it is supposed to be called by client application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this issue is resolved.
It is caused simply because session is so long and my terminal does not show full session.
So I make output to be witten in file.

```
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth \
--client-id 3hnanmnckc1b7lejgs1m8supri \
--auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH \
--auth-parameters \
    USERNAME=sekiguchi@mmmcorp.co.jp,PASSWORD=wancZJiw6@ >> cognito_initiate-auth.txt
```